Generating MapStore colour scheme for a polyline graph based on a code which identifies subgroups
I've a large water pipes dataset (7000km) made of polylines.
In this dataset sub groups of adjacent polylines are tagged with different codes and indicates water districts.
The number of districts is around 500 so It's not possible to find so many different colours or line patterns.
By the way It would be a nice start to use recurrent colours but not for adjacent districts, so It would be a readable theme.
The goal is then to expose this theme in a .sld on MapStore, so QGIS based.
I've tried automatic generators without a good output.
How can I generate a a theme wich cointains different colours at least for adjacent districts?

Please [Edit] the Question to contain a question.

Do you have polygon boundaries for the districts?

Yes but we're going to leave polygons for attributes on polilyne due to difficults drawing them when pipes from different districts intersects!

You want something like Topological coloring but for lines and per attribute group

Topological coloring is pretty cool but only works with polygons. I already have a code for each district. I wonder if there's a method to move on from this point!
